# xkeyval/lstinputlisting: "improper alphabetic constant" when used with linerange option

Tags: listings, xkeyval

I'm trying to use `xkeyval` to create a custom option (`\codeblock`) for my `lstinputlisting` (specifically for the `linerange` part). This is my MWE:

```
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\code}{}

\define@key{code}{block}{\renewcommand\codeblock{#1}}

\setkeys{code}{block=}
{}
\savekeys{code}{block}

\newcommand\code[1][]{
\setkeys{code}{#1}

\lstinputlisting[linerange=\codeblock,rangeprefix=//---,includerangemarker=false]{./listingwithoutcomments}  

}
\makeatother
```

I get the error:

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again>
                   \code
l.4 \code[block=inout]
```

This comes from using:

```
\linerange=\block
```

So I tried:

```
\linerange=\\block
```

... but then the resulting listing is completely empty.

I don't think there's anything wrong with my `xkeyval` syntax but I'm not sure how to get this working?

Comment: You're showing fragments only and it should by `linerange=\maxtestblock` most likely. You have `\newcommand{\code}...` twice as well... and `autogobble` is no key for `listings` environments

Comment: Sorry but how on Earth did you know about "maxtestblock"? I deliberately removed all instances of that and changed them all to "codeblock"

Comment: re. autogobble=true: http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/lstaddons/lstautogobble.pdf

Comment: The `lstaddons` stuff was not in your post above

Comment: I don't see why it should need to be: I've identified that the specific problem I'm having comes from `\linerange=\block` (this is the part that gives me the "!Improper alphabetic constant" error). Trying to escape `\\block` "works" in the sense that it compiles without errors, but that's all: the resulting listing is empty. 

And I'm sorry but I don't think I've ever put anything with "maxtestblock" anywhere in any of the posts I've actually finalised? Unless it was in an earlier edit?

Comment: I understand the need for MWEs and I've tried to focus on the specific problem. If I had posted all of my code, then doubtless it would have elicited responses similar to the ones here about "mountains of irrelevant code": 

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341571/improper-alphabetic-constant-with-listings-customized

Comment: An example of usage with (an approximation of) the expected output  would make the question answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this with:

```
\edef\dolisting{\noexpand\lstinputlisting[linerange=\codeblock,rangeprefix=//---,includerangemarker=false,language=maxj,frame=single]{./listingwithoutcomments}}
\dolisting
```